# TFS Changesets, list associated workItems and their parent workItems

Tags: changeset, workitem, tfs-workitem

While still getting to grips with all the features of TFS, one of my tasks is to produce a set of Release Notes for our Product by listing only the PBIs and BUGs (the use of PBI here as a type of workItem, just like a bug) against a set of changesets.

Other posts/blogs detail how to get a list of workItems from a set of changesets (which I can achieve using a PowerShell script) however, some of our related workItems in our system are tasks, therefore for each "task" associated to the Changeset, I need to go up a level to retrieve the parent PBI/BUG to list in our Release Notes (of course I may have to go up more than one level to get this).

I'm not entirely sure of all the features of PowerShell, perhaps there is an better alternative way to do this?  It has been suggested I use C#, but, I have no experience of C# at all so PowerShell may be my favoured option at this stage.

I also see a lot of posts saying that changesets should be related to tasks but then the Release notes should list the BUGs etc.  Therefore, how do other users provide a list of PBIs/BUGs from a set of changesets if they have been associated with tasks??

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Does no-one else have this issue?  If not then maybe someone can share what their Release Notes are based on and what they list.  Surely we can't be the only organisation whos Release Notes contain a list of Issues/BUGs !?

Comment: I didn't Autin, I will eventually write a PS script to retrieve the info but for now it is a manual.